# Inner product of two vector series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, inner-products

In a proof to a problem in optimization, there's this part I don't quite understand.

$(\Sigma_{i=1}^m \alpha_i\textbf{d}_i)^TQ(\Sigma_{i=1}^m \alpha_i\textbf{d}_i) = \Sigma_{i=1}^m \alpha_i^2\textbf{d}_i^TQ\textbf{d}_i$

where $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_m)^T \in \mathbb{R}^m$;
and $\textbf{d}_1, \textbf{d}_2, \cdots, \textbf{d}_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are $Q$-orthogonal, $\textbf{d}_i^TQ\textbf{d}_j = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$.

I tried to expand the left hand side by inserting the $Q$ to the right like this

$(\Sigma_{i=1}^m \alpha_i\textbf{d}_i)^T(\Sigma_{i=1}^m \alpha_iQ\textbf{d}_i) $

I believe I need to use some rule involving inner products, but I'm not exactly sure what to do next.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing some assumptions, this is in general not true. Pick $d_i=d, \alpha_i=1$ and $Q= Id_n$. Then your equation becomes $m^2\vert d\vert^2=m \vert d\vert^2$, which is not true in general.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Oh I forgot to mention that $\boldsymbol{d_1}, \boldsymbol{d_2}, \cdots, \boldsymbol{d_m}$ are $Q$-orthogonal. I will add that in the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Transpose distributes over sums. Then distribute the multiplication making a sum over all pairs of numbers between 1 and m.  Most of the terms will equal zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to develop the equation one step further. You have that:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\mathbf{d}_i\right)^\top Q\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\mathbf{d}_i\right) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\mathbf{d}_i\right)^\top\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_iQ\mathbf{d}_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m\alpha_i\alpha_j\mathbf{d}_i^\top Q\mathbf{d}_j.
$$
Now, since the $\mathbf{d}_i$ vectors are $Q$-orthogonal, all the terms such that $i\neq j$ are equal to zero, which leaves you with:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\mathbf{d}_i\right)^\top Q\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\mathbf{d}_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i^2\mathbf{d}_i^\top Q\mathbf{d}_i
$$